# Map of Maps of different types

Tags: java, factory

I need to initialize a couple of objects od different types from XML definitions to beans. I have directory structure:

```
data \
|_ plant \
|  |_ pine.xml
|  |_ cucumber.xml
|_ animal \
|  |_dog.xml
|  |_cat.xml
|_ fungus \
...
```

I want to store it orderly in two-level map: first level map holds second-level maps. Each second-level map holds objects of one type (of class plant/animal/fungus...). Each class extends the Dict class that has some common fields and methods (name/getName()/setName(), desc/getDesc()/setDesc(), toString(), equals() and the like.

Now, to facilitate creation of all this objects I want to have factory method Dict.fabricateAll(). And here is the problem: how to create second-level maps so that they had precise type parameters. I don't want HashMap<String, Dict> but HashMap<String, Plant>, HashMap<String, Animal> etc.

For now I have following code:

```
public static Map<String, Map<String, ? extends Dict>> fabricateAll() {
    File topDir = new File(Dict.defDir);
    File[] subDirs = topDir.listFiles();
    Map<String, Map<String, ? extends Dict>> dicts = new HashMap<>(subDirs.length);

    String type;
    String handle;
    Map<String, ? extends Dict> dict;

    for (File subDir : subDirs) {
        type = subDir.getName(); 
        File[] xmlFiles = subDir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {public boolean accept(File dir, String name) { return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xml"); }} );
        dict = new HashMap<>(xmlFiles.length);

        for (File defFile : xmlFiles) {
            handle = defFile.getName();
            handle = handle.substring(0, handle.lastIndexOf('.')-1);

            try {
                Class c = Class.forName(type);
                Constructor bob = c.getConstructor(Class.forName("java.lang.String"));
                dict.put(handle, bob.newInstance(handle));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        dicts.put(type, dict);
    }
    return dicts;
}
```

But there is a problem with line:
    dict.put(handle, bob.newInstance(handle));

Error message: "method put in interface Map<K,V> cannot be applied to given types. Required: String, CAP#1  Found: String,Object

Yes, that newInstance() generates Objects and probably there should be some cast but to what? I don't want just "(Dict)" here, I'd prefer "(Plant)", "(Animal)"... as appropriate. How to do that?

Comment: You're returning a `Map<String, Map<String, ? extends Dict>>`. So the client code can't know if the maps contain Plant, Cats or whatever. All it knows is that they're instances of Dict. So cast it to Dict, and everything will be fine. That said, I wouldn't use reflection to do that, but factories (one factory per type of Dict), which would allow doing what you want.

Comment: But Animal can run() while Plant cannot. If I cast it to Dict I have no possibility to invoke run() other than manual casting to Animal first.

As for 'one factory per Dict' approach: you mean I should have a 'public static fabricate(String handle)' in each of Dict subtypes and instead of calling 'bob.newInstance(handle)' to do:
    dict.put(handle, c.getMethod("fabricate", Class.forName("java.lang.String"))) ?

That gives the same error.

Comment: When you have a `Map<String, ? extends Dict>`, you have no way to know what the map contains anyway. All you can do is to test if the value is an instance of Plant or Animal (using `instanceof`), and cast the value to Plant or Animal. So what do you gain in making the map a `Map<String, Animal>`, since you return it as a `Map<String, ? extends Dict>`. Your factory idea is indeed a solution. You'll need the method to return Plant or Animal (depending on the class), and you'll need the map to be of type `Map<String, Plant>` or of type `Map<String, Animal>`, depending on the directory.

Answer (score 1):

Cast the object to a Dict.  That's the benefit of plolymorphism - you don't have to refer to specific sub-classes.  You can write you code with references only to the single base class, Dict.  This gives you:

- a) Loose coupling - no compile-time dependencies on specific sub-classes
- b) Exetensibility - you can add sub-classes without having to modify this code.

Yes, there are ways to achieve what you've asked for (a big switch statement comes to mind), but nothing that I would recommend.